# check_nrpe put $ at end of check string

Tags: powershell, nagios, dollar-sign

i've a problem with my powershell nagios script, mounted on a MS Windows Server 2008 64bit, with a NRPE_NT daemon.

I've declared the command like this:

```
command[check_files]=cmd /c echo C:\nrpe\libexec\check_file.ps1 $ARG1$; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -
```

I've set ExecutionPolicy as unrestricted

I've restart NRPE_NT Services and declared command on console, like this:

```
$USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -t 60 -c check_files -a $ARG1$
```

Now, why if i run it locally, it works good:

```
C:\>cmd /c echo C:\nrpe\libexec\_file.ps1 C:\nrpe; exit($lastexitcode)| powershell.exe -command -
No file/s present with this string
```

But if i run it by check_nrpe i receive this output:

**'-' was specified with the -Command parameter: no other arguments to -Command are permitted.**

In Debug mode, on NRPE.log i can see this:

> Running command: cmd /c echo C:\nrpe\libexec\check_file.ps1 C:\nrpe;
>   exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command - **$**
>
> Command completed with return code 0

Why in this way, check_nrpe add a dollar character ($) at end string, derailing the entire control ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help your situation, but I just figured out something in my environment that was causing something similar. Here was my NRPE command comfiguration:

```
command[foo]=grep file '^pattern$'
```

Everything was fine until I wanted to add another parameter after the `'^pattern$'` parameter... that new parameter (at the end of the command-line) would get an extra `$` appended to the end.

It seems that NRPE requires `$` to be escaped, otherwise it thinks that it's a variable reference and does odd things with it. I was expecting that the quoting would make it so that no escaping was required, but NRPE's configuration files don't follow shell-style quoting rules. So, changing my NRPE configuration to this solved my problem:

```
command[foo]=grep file '^pattern$$'
```

Note the double `$$` in the revised NRPE command definition.